# What does `@` mean at the start of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Consider the following line:

```
readonly private string TARGET_BTN_IMG_URL = @"\\ad1-sunglim\Test\";
```

In this line, why does @ need to be attached?

Comment: In javascript, that would be an error: `x = @"abc";`

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit for you :) *Runs off to post answer

Comment: Here comes 5 or 6 answers saying the same thing...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It denotes a literal string, in which the '\' character does not indicate an escape sequence.

Comment: "You could to double each backslash with same effect: `TARGET_BTN_IMG_URL = "\\\\ad1-sunglim\\Test\\";`"

Comment: Yeah, but it is not as easy to read, which is why this option exists.

Answer (score 12):

@ tells C# to treat that as a <s>literal string</s> [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx). For example:

```
string s = "C:\Windows\Myfile.txt";
```

is an error because `\W` and `\M` are not valid escape sequences. You need to write it this way instead:

```
string s = "C:\\Windows\\Myfile.txt";
```

To make it clearer, you can use a literal string, which does not recognize \ as a special character. Hence:

```
string s = @"C:\Windows\Myfile.txt";
```

is perfectly okay.

---

EDIT: MSDN provides these examples:

```
string a = "hello, world";                  // hello, world
string b = @"hello, world";                 // hello, world
string c = "hello \t world";                // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";               // hello \t world
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";      // Joe said "Hello" to me
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";     // Joe said "Hello" to me
string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt";   // \\server\share\file.txt
string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";      // \\server\share\file.txt
string i = "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree";
string j = @"one
two
three";
```

Comment: It's worth noting the specific case of wanting to put a quote `"` in a verbatim string. This is possible using double quote marks `""`. This can be seen in the `@"Joe said ""Hello"" to me"` example above).

Comment: Offtopic: Where did that "verbatim" prefix originated?

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: Err.. because that's what Eric Lippert + friends decided to use when they designed C#?

Comment: @Noldorin: *Normal* string literals can't span multiple lines. *Verbatim* string literals can span multiple lines.

Comment: @Billy I meant, why are they called  `verbatim` what's the origin the *verbatim*  word ( aside from the company with that name )

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: The word `verbatim` is standard English. ( http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbatim ) It means "literally" or "exactly" or "word-for-word". For example, "The student copied the teacher's notes verbatim."

Comment: @Billy Oh I see, I thought it was one of those slangs with obscure origin, thanks.

Comment: @Billy: Yeah, you know what I mean. :)

Answer (score 2):

because you string contains escape sequence "\". in order to tell compiler not to treat "\" as escape sequence you have to use "@".